# set Inflate layout to smaller

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, layout

i have some problems with my layout, this is the capture of my layout inflater

[image]

the layout is to big and the button are in wrong place, i don't use a title but there is a black title background in there

i just want to make it smaller like piano tiles layout

[image]

can anyone help me to fix this?

this is my `layout.xml` data that will show inflater layout in `menu.java`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundblankwhite"
    android:gravity="center|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10sp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/exitimage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/textinflateexit"
        android:singleLine="true" >

        <requestFocus />
    </TextView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonexityes"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonquityes" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonexitno"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonquitno" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my `menu.java` that have a button to display my inflate layout

```
    public class menu extends Activity {

    private Context context = this; 



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);


         Button exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);
         exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

             @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                   final Dialog openDialog = new Dialog(context);
                   openDialog.setContentView(R.layout.inflatequitapp);
                   TextView dialogTextContent = (TextView)openDialog.findViewById(R.id.exitimage);

                   Button dialogExitButton = (Button)openDialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonexityes);
                   dialogExitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){                                      
                      @Override
                      public void onClick(View v) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                          // if this button is clicked, close
                          // current activity
                         menu.this.finish();
                                              } 
                   });
                   Button dialogCloseButton = (Button)openDialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonexitno);
                   dialogCloseButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                      @Override
                      public void onClick(View v) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                          openDialog.dismiss();
                      }                                                                             
                 });                   
                 openDialog.show();
              }
           });
    }


    @Override           
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // do nothing.
    }           

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have change a bit variable to check at my end..please do change variables,class to match at your end...

MainActivity.java

```
 ///---////
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


         Button exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but);
         exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

             @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                   final Dialog openDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                   openDialog.setContentView(R.layout.main);
                   openDialog.setTitle("Confirm Exit");
                   TextView dialogTextContent = (TextView)openDialog.findViewById(R.id.exitimage);

                   Button dialogExitButton = (Button)openDialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonexityes);
                   dialogExitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){                                      
                      @Override
                      public void onClick(View v) {
                         finish();
                         } 
                   });
                   Button dialogCloseButton = (Button)openDialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonexitno);
                   dialogCloseButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                      @Override
                      public void onClick(View v) {
                          openDialog.dismiss();
                      }                                                                             
                 });                   
                 openDialog.show();
              }
           });

}
```

Dialog xml file..

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:gravity="center|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10sp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/exitimage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Are You Sure!!" >

    <requestFocus />
</TextView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonexityes"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="Yes" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonexitno"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="No" />
    </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you have to used below code for dialog

```
private void forgotPasswordDialog() {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

        final View dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_forgot_password, null);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.PauseDialog);

        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        dialog.setView(dialogView);

        dialog.show();

        final EditText edtUserNameDialog = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edtUserNameDialog);
        edtUserNameDialog.setText(edtUserName.getText());

        final Button btnSubmit = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (!FieldsValidator.validateUsername(edtUserNameDialog)) {

                    //forgotPasswordDialog();

                } else if (!checkDMSID()) {

                    KeyboardUtils.hideKeyboard(edtUserNameDialog);

                    dialog.dismiss();

                } else {

                    KeyboardUtils.hideKeyboard(edtUserNameDialog);

                    forgotPassword(edtUserNameDialog.getText().toString());

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });

        final Button btnCancel = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                KeyboardUtils.hideKeyboard(edtUserNameDialog);

                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });

    }
```